# This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Account lacks permission to send Envelopes over SMS

Tags: docusignapi

We are working on integrating e-signing over SMS feature with our application using the Docusign APIs. In the production account, it gives this error:

`This Account lacks sufficient permissions. Account lacks permission to send Envelopes over SMS.`

1. We have enabled Allow SMS delivery to recipients in 'Sending Settings' of eSignature Admin [image: screenshot].
2. Our existing 'Embedded' and 'Remote (over email)' esigning operations are working fine.
3. Only with this new SMS feature, we get above error.
4. We are also sure that our account supports SMS. Our older plan had embedded + email + API support. We upgraded recently for SMS.

Let me know if any other information is needed

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening a case through our [support center](https://support.docusign.com/en/contactSupport) and check if this feature is enabled. It may be the case where is in your plan but is not enabled